# Are there any bad side effects of having a Dislike or Downvote button on a forum-based community?

Tags: user-behavior, problem-users, site-growth, web-forums, voting

We are still developing our forum community, and we're going to be having a "like button" where users can like a post or replies that they find interesting or like a post from a reputable or contributive user they admire..

So, my question, will having a Dislike Button cause any problems or destroy the connections between users? what are your experience with this? your answers will be really appreciated, thank you in advance..

Comment: Related/Dupes: http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/477/78 and http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1040/78